# Logging swiftmailer send() activity in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, logging, swiftmailer, symfony-2.2

Im using swiftmailer for sending mails from my symfony2.2 project. Is there a way to log globally all email info and send results?

It  would be great if mailer send() method have trigger somę event, but I can't see it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it this way:

#### 1. My service configuration

```
# /src/Tiriana/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
     swiftmailer.class:  Tiriana\MyBundle\Util\MailerWrapper
```

#### 2. Mailer wraper service

It extends `Swift_Mailer`, because it is passed to different classes expecting mailer to be instance of `Swift_Mailer`. 
And it creates `Swift_Mailer` instance as a field, because... `$transport` is `private` in `\Swith_Mailer` ([link](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php#L19)). Code would be so much better if `$transport` was `protected`...

```
// /src/Tiriana/MyBundle/Util/MailerWrapper.php
namespace Tiriana\MyBundle\Util;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

class MailerWrapper extends \Swift_Mailer
{
    private $_logger;

    /** @var \Swift_Mailer */
    private $_mailer;

    public function send(\Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
    {
        $this->_log('BEFORE SEND');  // <-- add your logic here
        $ret = $this->_mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
        $this->_log('AFTER SEND');  // <-- add your logic here

        return $ret;
    }

    /** @return Logger */
    public function getLogger()
    {
        return $this->_logger;
    }

    protected function _log($msg)
    {
        $this->getLogger()->debug(__CLASS__ . ": " . $msg);
    }

    public function __construct(\Swift_Transport $transport, Logger $logger)
    {
        /* we need _mailer because _transport is private
           (not protected) in Swift_Mailer, unfortunately... */
        $this->_mailer = parent::newInstance($transport);
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public static function newInstance(\Swift_Transport $transport)
    {
        return new self($transport);
    }

    public function getTransport()
    {
        return $this->_mailer->getTransport();
    }

    public function registerPlugin(Swift_Events_EventListener $plugin)
    {
        $this->getTransport()->registerPlugin($plugin);
    }
}
```

#### 3. Bundle builder

```
// /src/Tiriana/MyBundle/TirianaMyBundle.php
namespace Tiriana\MyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use Tiriana\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceSwiftMailer;

class TirianaMyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideServiceSwiftMailer());  // <-- ADD THIS LINE
    }
}
```

#### 4. And `OverrideServiceSwiftMailer` class

```
// /src/Tiriana/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/OverrideServiceSwiftMailer.php
namespace Tiriana\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class OverrideServiceSwiftMailer implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        /* @var $definition \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\DefinitionDecorator */
        $definition = $container->findDefinition('mailer');
        $definition->addArgument(new Reference('logger'));
        /* add more dependencies if you need - i.e. event_dispatcher */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

This question was answered already, This solution is better for Symfony 4 combined with Monolog. It is based on umpirsky his Answer. But without the overhead of a custom file logger.

*Note: Logs will be placed in ./var/logs/...*

**App\Util\MailLoggerUtil.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Util;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LogLevel;
use Swift_Events_SendEvent;
use Swift_Events_SendListener;

class MailerLoggerUtil implements Swift_Events_SendListener
{
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * MailerLoggerUtil constructor.
     *
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt
     */
    public function beforeSendPerformed(Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt)
    : void
    {
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * @param Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt
     */
    public function sendPerformed(Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt)
    : void
    {
        $level   = $this->getLogLevel($evt);
        $message = $evt->getMessage();

        $this->logger->log(
            $level,
            $message->getSubject().' - '.$message->getId(),
            [
                'result'  => $evt->getResult(),
                'subject' => $message->getSubject(),
                'to'      => $message->getTo(),
                'cc'      => $message->getCc(),
                'bcc'     => $message->getBcc(),
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getLogLevel(Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt)
    : string
    {
        switch ($evt->getResult()) {
            // Sending has yet to occur
            case Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_PENDING:
                return LogLevel::DEBUG;

            // Email is spooled, ready to be sent
            case Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_SPOOLED:
                return LogLevel::DEBUG;

            // Sending failed
            default:
            case Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_FAILED:
                return LogLevel::CRITICAL;

            // Sending worked, but there were some failures
            case Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_TENTATIVE:
                return LogLevel::ERROR;

            // Sending was successful
            case Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_SUCCESS:
                return LogLevel::INFO;
        }
    }
}
```

**services.yaml**

```
App\Util\MailLoggerUtil:
    arguments: ["@logger"]
    tags:
      - { name: monolog.logger, channel: mailer }
      - { name: "swiftmailer.default.plugin" }
```

If you want the mailer logs to be in another channel add this:

**dev/monolog.yaml (optional)**

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        mailer:
            level:    debug
            type:     stream
            path:     '%kernel.logs_dir%/mailer.%kernel.environment%.log'
            channels: [mailer]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - it's been really helpful!

Comment: great answer! Working fine also with Symfony 3

Answer (score 9):

Service:

```
class MessageFileLogger implements Swift_Events_SendListener
{
    private $filename;

    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->read();
    }

    public function clear()
    {
        $this->write(array());
    }

    public function beforeSendPerformed(Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt)
    {
        $messages = $this->read();
        $messages[] = clone $evt->getMessage();

        $this->write($messages);
    }

    public function sendPerformed(Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt)
    {
    }

    private function read()
    {
        if (!file_exists($this->filename)) {
            return array();
        }

        return (array) unserialize(file_get_contents($this->filename));
    }

    private function write(array $messages)
    {
        file_put_contents($this->filename, serialize($messages));
    }
}
```

Config:

```
services:
    umpirsky.mailer.message_file_logger:
        class: MessageFileLogger
        arguments:
            - %kernel.logs_dir%/mailer.log
        tags:
            - { name: swiftmailer.plugin }
```

Comment: This should be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following to the 'services' section of your configuration will print interaction with the transport to stdout (which can be useful if you're debugging by using the console commands, e.g. 'swiftmailer:email:send' or 'swiftmailer:spool:send'):

```
services:

    # (...)

    swiftmailer.plugins.loggerplugin:
        class: 'Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin'
        arguments: ['@swiftmailer.plugins.loggerplugin.logger']
        tags: [{ name: 'swiftmailer.default.plugin' }]

    swiftmailer.plugins.loggerplugin.logger:
        class: 'Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger'
        arguments: [false]
```

Example output, using SMTP transport to localhost:

```
$ app/console swiftmailer:email:send --subject="Test" --body="Yo! :)" --from="user@example.com" --to="user@example.com"

++ Starting Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport
<< 220 example.com ESMTP Exim 4.86 Thu, 07 Jan 2016 13:57:43 +0000

>> EHLO [127.0.0.1]

<< 250-example.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP

++ Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport started
>> MAIL FROM: <user@example.com>

<< 250 OK

>> RCPT TO: <user@example.com>

<< 451 Temporary local problem - please try later

!! Expected response code 250/251/252 but got code "451", with message "451 Temporary local problem - please try later"
>> RSET

<< 250 Reset OK

Sent 0 emails

++ Stopping Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport
>> QUIT

<< 221 example.com closing connection

++ Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport stopped
```

Comment: one small thing is missing - if you have more then 1 mailer (or non default mailer name) `tags: [{ name: 'swiftmailer.%mailer_name%.plugin' }]`. Also you should add `logging: true` to the mailer configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `SwiftMailer` with your own custom mailer class. Like,

```
class MyMailer
{
    /**
     * @var \Swift_Mailer
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * Mail the specified mailable using swift mailer.
     * 
     * @param SwiftMessage $swiftMessage
     */
    public function mail(\SwiftMessage $swiftMessage)
    {
        // PRESEND ACTIONS

        $sent = $this->mailer->send($swiftMessage);

        // POST SEND ACTIONS
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. It's ok, but it requires me to change all the mailer -> send() calls in my code. This is something I want to avoid. It would be ideal if I could overwrite the mailer service, and... pass the previously defined mailer service to it :)   - I'm currently trying to find the place where 'mailer' service is being defined, so I now what params and args it receives , but I just can't seem to find it...