# Symfony/Swiftmailer emails not sent and no logs

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer, mailjet

I'm having problems trying to send emails via swiftmailer and mailjet as SMTP server. Everything used to worked perfectly and then something broke. I'm trying to find out what's the problem.

The doc seems to say swiftmailer generates a log in debug mode. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#logging

So I activated the debug mode in app.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);

// ...
```

When I launch the command everything seems perfect

```
sudo -u www-data php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
[2015-11-20 22:14:47] Processing default mailer... 6 emails sent
```

But no email received, the mailjet dashboard indicates no emails has been send to it.
And nothing in the logs.

So where swiftmailer is supposed to write its logs ?

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033210/logging-swiftmailer-send-activity-in-symfony2) but I don't want to change my code that much if it is possible. Plus I assume that if swiftmailer offers a logging parameter it can write some logs.

By the way sending emails via Gmail works perfectly, but still doesn't generate any log

Thanks for help!

Comment: you had a look at /app/logs/dev/dev.log?

Answer (score 1):

I lead Developers Relations at Mailjet.

Could you please reach us over email at dev@mailjet.com to give us more details about your Mailjet account, for us to check everything is OK on our side?

Thanks